# Use Check Box (Form Control) to filter out specific item from Pivot Chart - no response from button?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to filter an item out from a pivot chart. I want to remove the "Horse" element from the chart.

[image]

I've set up a table with 4 animals, with associated costs, and then pivoted the table into a similar Pivot Table, and then generated a Pivot Chart based off the Pivot Chart. Next to that is a button, which I've assigned a macro to, which *should* allow me to remove "Horse" from the chart. However, when clicking the button, there's no response. Any ideas? Here's my code below.

```
Sub RemoveHorse()

   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
   With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Animal")
       If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
           .PivotItems("Horse").Visible = False
       End If
   End With

   With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Animal")
       If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
           .PivotItems("Horse").Visible = True
       End If
   End With
End Sub
```

As far as I can follow (first time trying to use Excel VBA), the Pivot Chart is first activated. Then, the "Animal" field is selected, and then the status of the checkbox is selected. If it's False (off), the "Horse" element is hidden from the chart, and if the checkbox is set as True, then the element is shown.

Don't seem to get a response from the button however. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Can you please confirm whether your checkbox is in fact a Form control, and not an ActiveX control?

Comment: @Domenic it's a form control.

Answer (score 0):

First, for a Form control checkbox, you would refer to it as follows . . .

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 1")
```

Secondly, to select/check the checkbox, you would need to assign it the value xlOn.  And to de-select/uncheck it, you would need to assign it the value xlOff.

Therefore, to check whether the checkbox is checked . . .

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn then
```

To check whether the checkbox is unchecked . . .

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = xlOff then
```

However, your code could be re-written as follows . . .

```
Sub RemoveHorse()

    Dim chbx As CheckBox
    Set chbx = Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 1")
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Animal")
        .PivotItems("Horse").Visible = (chbx.Value = xlOn)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Change the sheet name accordingly.

Comment: I love you. Thanks for this. Works flawlessly :)

Comment: How would I get the chart to adjust the scale automatically as I filter items on and off?

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!

Comment: First, right-click the Value axis, and then select Format Axis from the context menu.  Then select Axis Options from the Task pane on the right.  Then under Axis Options in the Axis Options tab, click on reset for both the Minimum and Maximum bounds to set it to Auto.  And do the same thing for the Minor and Major units.